Getting line 593 Killed error after antsRegistrationSynQuick with mask
I am trying to register a subject CT scanner with 8 electrodes on the brain (Hounsfield > 3000) on the MNI MRI.
antsRegistrationSyNQuick.sh -d 3 -f subject_ct.nii.gz -m MNI.nii.gz -o reg_masked_ -t s -x mask.nii
The mask.nii is a binary image where voxels with intensities < 2500 (excluding electrodes and including the bone) are 1 and the rest is 0.
However, I get this error:
line 593: 176212 Killed                  $COMMAND
What is wrong?
I was expecting to get a fairly good registration of the MNI on the subject CT, then use the inverse affine to get electrode coordinates in MNI space.
